# React native and Jest: How can I execute code that uses fetch?

Tags: javascript, react-native, jasmine, jestjs

I have some code that does this:

```
export default () => {
  return fetch('example.com');
};
```

There is no other code in this file.  When I run a test that calls this function, the test gives me this error:

```
    ReferenceError: fetch is not defined
```

I'm using jest and react native.  Since fetch is a global, I'm not sure how to work around this issue.

Here are my dev dependencies:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "8.0.1",
    "babel-jest": "21.2.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "4.0.0",
    "code-push-cli": "^2.1.0-beta",
    "eslint": "4.8.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "2.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "2.3.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.4.0",
    "jest": "21.2.1",
    "prettier": "1.7.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.0.0",
    "sentry-cli-binary": "^1.21.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!react-native|react-navigation)/"
    ]
  }
```

Comment: Are you running the given function directly in your browser? Or are you executing it as a test? From the comments in my answer, it sounds like your code works in a browser but does not when you run a test. These details should be included in your question, along with a sample test that causes the error.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice it works as react-native, but not in the test.

Comment: May I ask the obvious why not just mocking fetch? or is it some sort of integration test?

Comment: @Daniel because this is legacy code and I'm trying to put it under test with as little modification as possible.  IMO, mocking would be the 2nd step, not the first.

Comment: @DanielKaplan you won't need to modify your application code if you just mock it. I've put an example on my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless is an integration test where you actually want to `fetch` an HTTP resource, you could simply mock `fetch` in your test:

**App Code**

```
async function someFuncAsync() {
    return fetch('http://example.com');
}
```

**Test Code**

```
const mockResponse = (status, statusText, response) => {
        return new Response(response, {
            status: status,
            statusText: statusText,
            headers: {
                'Content-type': 'application/json'
            }
        });
    }; 

describe('foo tests', () => {

    it('mocks fetch', () => {
        window.fetch = jest
            .fn()
            .mockImplementation(async () => mockResponse(200, null, JSON.stringify({ foo: 'bar' })));

        return someFuncAsync().then(async (response) => {
            const result = await response.json();
            expect(result).toEqual({ foo: 'bar' })
        })
    })
});
```

Comment: So because you're creating it on `window`, the `someFuncAsync` will have access to fetch?  This works.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you are running your code on a browser which does not support `fetch()` natively. In order to support such browsers you need a polyfill such as isomorphic-fetch. Add this library to your dependencies then import it wherever you need to use it:

```
import fetch from 'isomorphic-fetch';
```

Comment: I've my real code doesn't seem to need that import to function.  Wy do I need to do that for it to be testable?  Is this the only way to resolve this issue?  It seems like the jest preset should understand that `fetch` is a global.

Comment: @DanielKaplan Your title asks about testing...but your actual question is about a compiler error which has nothing to do with tests. See my edited answer.

Comment: @DanielKaplan Please post a new comment rather than editing your old one.